# DotNetZip, Powershell and Relative Paths

Tags: powershell, dotnetzip

I want to zip some selected folders into an archive only with their **relative paths**.

Some of them have the same folder names (all release-folders, all debug-folders).

The filtering works fine and I have called set-location prior to get-children command.

What is the easiest way to do this job?

Do I really have to implement something like this

```
foreach ($o in $children)
{   $relPath = $o.FullName.Substring(subPath.Length);
    $relPath = $relPath.Substring(0, relPath.LastIndexOf(@"\"));
    zip.AddFolder($o.Name, $relPath);
}
```

Does someone can provide me an example?

Thx

Comment: It will be good if you give some concrete example of what you want to be done. The question is very vague

Answer (score 0):

When I need to handle relative paths, I do something like this:

```
$basePath = "C:\MyBasePath"
$newBasePAth = "C:\NewBasePath"

$files = Get-ChildItem $basePath
$newFileNames = foreach ($f in $files) {
    $f.Fullname.Replace($basePath, $newBasePath)
}
```

Make sure  the pattern of slashes you use is the same in $basePath and $newBasePath (use .Trim() to be sure)

Hope this helps

Comment: I want to select special files (or folders) to be included in a zip-archive with their relative path. I'm trying to do this with DotNetZip.

Comment: I want to select special files (or folders) to be included in a zip-archive with their relative path to the path I set with set-location. I'm trying to do this with DotNetZip. But there is always a fullpath. So I need to extract the first part (as winzip does automatically). Another problem is, when I include complete folders. Some of them have the same name, but different paths, and I'm not able to add a second folder by its name.

Comment: This is actually one of those cases where you should probably just use an existing module instead of writing your own.  It sounds like you're having problems wrapping DotNetZip, and creating your own extraction command.

You can check out either PowerShellPack (which includes Copy-ToZip, which does this) or PowerShell Community Extensions (PSCX), which includes the more versatile Expand-Archive (this does .7z, .zip, .gzip, .iso, and more)

Answer (score 0):

I finally implemented this and it works with the relative paths:

```
function ZipUp-Files ( $mychildren )
{
  foreach ($o in $mychildren) 
  {
        $e= $zipfile.AddDirectory($o.FullName,$o.fullname.substring($pwd.path.length));
  }
}

$children =get-childitem -recurse -force | where-object {$_.psiscontainer} | where {$_.name -match $teststring} 

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\dotNetZip\zip-v1.9\Release\Ionic.Zip.dll");
$zipfile =  new-object Ionic.Zip.ZipFile($ziptarget);
$zipfile.UseZip64WhenSaving= [Ionic.Zip.Zip64Option]::Always
$zipfile.MaxOutPutSegmentSize=734003200
ZipUp-Files $children
$zipfile.Save("c:\temp\arc_rel.zip")
$zipfile.Dispose()
```